# What is the distribution of illegal acts defined by the Computer Misuse Act actually done by children in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, law, crime

[The UK National Crime Agency](https://nationalcrimeagency.gov.uk/news/one-in-five-children-found-to-engage-in-illegal-activity-online) has annonced that one in five children are being criminalised by the [Computer Misuse Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/contents) (CMA).  They warn of life changing consequences for the children involved.

They give a few example, which seem to me to fall into one of three categories which all have very different interpretations:

#### Serious Crimes

Eg. "downloading software to get access to someone else’s device" and "engage in DDoS-ing".  These are serious hacking charges.  If a large part of the one in five children are involved with this sort of thing that is something that is worth knowing.

#### Crimes without the CMA

Eg. "buying something using the saved card details on someone else’s account.  Gamers who make in-game purchases without the permission of the account holder".  I think this would be illegal without the CMA, probably theft or fraud.  If such things ever get to criminal convictions I would be surprised if the CMA charges would be any more than a footnote after more serious offences.  If a large part of the one in five is this I would feel the press release is being somewhat disingenuous.

#### Things that are complex for adults to understand

Eg. "trying to access a protected server".  The definition of [unauthorised access to a server on the public internet](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/90992/computer-misuse-act-1990-definition-of-unauthorised) is difficult.  [I cannot work out](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/98944/what-does-unauthorised-mean-in-regards-to-access-to-web-sites) how to go from that law and answers on law.SE to "am I allowed to access this game server I found on discord/[shodan](https://shodan.io/)".  If a large part of the one in five children are being criminalised by this then it seems more information could solve the problem.

Do we know anything about the distribution of crimes within this one in five that the National Crime Agency has announced?

Comment: This seems like a question for Law SE.

Comment: And your wording "children are being criminalised" sounds a bit pushy to me.

Comment: @Fizz Is there a more neutral wording for a law applying to a certain group? Affected maybe? Also I don't think this is a law question unless it's about the interpretation of "trying to access a protected server". This question simply seems to ask to quantify the extent to which parts of this law apply to children.

Comment: "The definition of unauthorised access to a server on the public internet is difficult." This may be a better question for the law.stackexhange because are experts in explaining laws. The definition should be absolutely clear for law people.

Comment: The linked answer explains where the definition of unauthorised can be found and quotes the law. I think people tend to know and/or it ends to be quite clear when they are doing something authorised or unauthorised. The equivalent of an open door with a sign saying all welcome vs. the equivalent of climbing over a stranger's fence in the dark and trying all their doors and windows  to see if any are unlocked.

Comment: I think the catch all that gets the 1 in 5 children is 'software that can be used to get access to someone else's device'. Depending on how you interpret this, a large amount of perfectly legitimate software falls under that.

Comment: For example,  most schools have a "no games" rule for their computers.  Many students will try to find ways to play games on school computers, sometimes by using vpl or similar software to evade blocks that the school has put on their computers, or sites like "unblockedgames.com" This would seem to be a violation of CMA, but probably not one that the police would be very interested in.

Comment: The 1 in 5 stat is from a survey of children. It seems the NCA has not published the survey data. The NCA might provide it if asked.

Comment: it's an interesting question, upvoted. I don't think it belongs to the law stackexchange.

Comment: An important part of this question is that all children asked could be, in the UK, held (at least partially) responsible before the court. The age group for this survey was 10–16. In a lot of countries, [criminal responsability would be negated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_criminal_responsibility) for some or even all of the children because of their age.

Comment: @Lag I link two questions. [The one I asked](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/98944/41938) presents [a situation](https://maia.crimew.gay/posts/how-to-hack-an-airline/) where I cannot work out where the line is.  I can see very similar situations that result from trying to access game servers, which I took them to mean.

Comment: @User65535 I think if you don't know that you're not authorised to peruse an airline's unsecured server and look through its employee databases, no fly lists and terrorist screening databases you should err on the side of caution and not dabble in such activities.

Comment: @Lag Looking at the dev version of the web site is where the question mark comes.  What if the ftp site was also public?  Would that be authorised?  And we are talking about children here, right?

Comment: @User65535 Are 'you' (a) "a person who has responsibility for the dev website and is entitled to determine whether the act may be done" or (b) "has consent to the act from any such person"? Or did 'you' happen across the dev website while bored browsing Chinese Shodan, looking for exposed servers that may have interesting things, and had no prior knowledge of it or connection to it? As for children, the examples at https://nationalcrimeagency.gov.uk/cyber-choices either knew they should not commit those acts but did so anyway (as some kids do) or they were failed by their parents/educators.

Comment: Hacking the overly restricted yet poorly secured school computers seems like an obvious candidste - who on stackoverflow hasn't done that? Circumventing parental controls at home is another candidate, as is cheating in an online game, trying to guess a classmate's facebook password, or buying a lootbox without parents' permission. without further break down the statistic is indeed useless.

Comment: A common behaviour by children is to give false information about their age, in order to get access to sites or features restricted to adults or older children.  When they do this, it might then be deemed to be unauthorised access to a computer.